# Jackson XML write stream array

Tags: java, xml, jackson

How do I write an array of objects using a Jackson's stream XML API? I've done that using JSON, but XML fails miserably. Working proof of concept for JSON:

```
    List<Item> values = Arrays.asList(new Item("hello"), new Item("world"))
    OutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    factory.setCodec(objectMapper);
    JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(stream, JsonEncoding.UTF8);


    generator.writeStartArray();

    for(Item value : values) {
        generator.writeObject(value);
    }

    generator.writeEndArray();
    generator.close();
```

I've tried using the same code changing the generator to XML

```
    XmlFactory factory = new XmlFactory();
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    factory.setCodec(xmlMapper);
    ToXmlGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(stream, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
```

I get such exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Trying to output second root, <Item>
```

I've tried some other things, like setting next names, writing start/end of object, but all I get are different exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Using "generator.writeObject(values);" would have been enough.

```java
List<Item> values = Arrays.asList(new Item("hello"), new Item("world"));

XmlFactory factory = new XmlFactory();
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
factory.setCodec(xmlMapper);
ToXmlGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(new File("test,xml"), JsonEncoding.UTF8);

generator.writeObject(values);
generator.close();
```

and when I open the test xml  I see

```xml
<ArrayList>
  <item>
    <data>hello</data>
  </item>
  <item>
    <data>world</data>
  </item>
</ArrayList>
```

same applies to json

```java
List<Item> values = Arrays.asList(new Item("hello"), new Item("world"));
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
factory.setCodec(objectMapper);
JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(new File("test,json"), JsonEncoding.UTF8);
generator.writeObject(values);
generator.close();
```

test.json

```json
[ {
  "data" : "hello"
}, {
  "data" : "world"
} ]
```

[Here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/java-examlpes/tree/master/jackson-xm-json-write) is working example.